# OpenGL contants with equal value

Tags: opengl

I was just wandering whether openGL has 2 **constants**/symbols that have the same value.

Comment: Which constants are you referring to?

Comment: For example GL_BLEND and GL_MODERLVIEW or GL_TEXTURE_2D etc.

Comment: Why not check the header file yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, for tokens that identify specific states this never happens, but it is context-specific. As elicited in other responses, some of the more general-purpose constants that refer to concepts rather than states, will alias; as will constants that are used for the purpose of masking individual attributes in a bitfield. Within the same context, two distinct tokens will never have the same values as it would be impossible to distinguish between all of the valid passed values. However, for tokens that cannot be used meaningfully in the same function: `GL_TRIANGLES` (0x04) and `GL_LINE_BITS` (0x04) this happens frequently.

Extensions, which are how OpenGL grows, allocate named constants by giving vendors a portion of the enumerant space to use for their extensions. This prevents collisions between legitimate/approved extensions and allows the extension to be revised over time and introduce new tokens.

Having said that, in the process of an extension migrating from EXT status to ARB status and eventual adoption into core GL, sometimes the constant values for tokens that refer to the same thing are re-used. Case in point: `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT` (from the EXT FBO extension) is **`0x8D40`** and `GL_FRAMEBUFFER` (from the ARB extension / core GL 3+) is also **`0x8D40`**.

On a side-note, the enumerant space used by OpenGL is actually only 16-bit (despite `GLenum` being defined as a 32-bit data type). There are a maximum of 65,535 distinct constant values that the API can use so reuse is inevitable.

Answer (score 3):

There's at least one pair:

```
#define GL_FALSE                          0
...
#define GL_NONE                           0
```

Comment: Hm good point there, but I mean those of meaning for settings.. like those being enabled by glEnable or glMatrixMode etc.